# Quarkus Custom authorization interceptors

Tags: authorization, openid-connect, interceptor, quarkus, requestfiltering

I have a Quarkus microservice doing authentication and authorization with Keycloak using quarkus-oidc and quarkus-keycloak-authorization extensions.

I need to additionally implement following two request interceptors/filters:

1. A filter before any auth logic kicks in. This is to copy token from query param to header (required for web sockets). What should be the priority of this filter?
2. A filter to have custom authorization logic. This should be executed after all authentication and keycloak authorization logic but just before API execution? What should be priority of this filter?

I tried putting @Priority(Interceptor.Priority.PLATFORM_BEFORE) and @Prematching also to my filter, but even this is being called after OIDC kicks in.

Also, is there any way to support extending quarkus oidc logic to include custom code?

I am unable to get the priority of  oidc and keycloak-auth interceptors (knowing these could help me deciding the priority of my filters). Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the answer from quarkus google groups.

For #2, ContainerRequestFilter with any priority (should not be @Prematching) will serve the purpose.
Other option is to have custom HttpSecurityPolicy. This would be called after authentication.

```
package org.acme.security.keycloak.authorization;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import io.quarkus.security.identity.SecurityIdentity;
import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;

@ApplicationScoped
public class SecurityHandler implements io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityPolicy
{
    @Override
    public Uni<CheckResult> checkPermission(RoutingContext request, Uni<SecurityIdentity> identity, AuthorizationRequestContext requestContext)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(LoggingFilter.class).infof("================ custom permission");
        return Uni.createFrom().item(CheckResult.PERMIT);
    }

}
```

For #1, we can have Vertx @RouteFilter

Sample filter:
Just note the priority. Higher the priority, first it will get called.

```
package org.acme.security.keycloak.authorization;

import io.quarkus.vertx.web.RouteFilter;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;

public class WSAuthFilter
{
    @RouteFilter(1000) 
     void myFilter(RoutingContext rc) {
         rc.request().headers().add("Authorization", rc.request().query());
         rc.next(); 
    }
}
```