# OpenID access token sent in body, put it in the header

Tags: vert.x, quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I have a legacy jax-rs request. I can't change it. It's body has OpenID access token. I want to validate it using quarkus-oidc. My idea is to read the body and put token to `Authorization` header.

I tried to use `ContainerRequestFilter` with and without [quarkus proactive auth](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-built-in-authentication#proactive-authentication), but looks like quarkus auth checks happen way before jax-rs, somewhere in vert.x

I found this [Quarkus Custom authorization interceptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62495685/quarkus-custom-authorization-interceptors), but it works only if access token is in a query string.

How do i read request body and write access token in the headers before quarkus-oidc checks access token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed! Not sure if this is most correct way to do what i want, but looks like it works reliably.

```java
import io.quarkus.vertx.web.RouteFilter;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod;
import io.vertx.ext.web.RoutingContext;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.BodyHandler;

public class JoinServerRequestSecurityRouterFilter {
    @RouteFilter(3000)
    public void extractBody(RoutingContext context) {
        if (context.request().method() != HttpMethod.POST) {
            context.next();
            return;
        }

        if (!"/session-service/join".equals(context.normalizedPath())) {
            context.next();
            return;
        }
        BodyHandler bodyHandler = BodyHandler.create(false);
        bodyHandler.handle(context);
    }
    @RouteFilter(3000 - 1)
    public void copyAccessToken(RoutingContext context) {
        if (context.request().method() != HttpMethod.POST) {
            context.next();
            return;
        }

        if (!"/session-service/join".equals(context.normalizedPath())) {
            context.next();
            return;
        }

        if (context.getBodyAsJson() == null) {
            context.next();
            return;
        }
        String accessToken = context.getBodyAsJson().getString("accessToken");
        context.request().headers().add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        context.next();
    }
}
```